# How to make a scalable ListView item background colour?

Tags: android, listview

I want to make a scalable ListView item background colour from green to red that scales every day by one tick. For example 365 days, from day 0 it's green and with each day it get's more red but not totaly red and finally on day 365 it get's totaly red. How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ColorDrawable` to create a color for each item, according to its color, and assign it as the item view's background. To get a color between two colors with a percentage, you can use `ArgbEvaluator`:

```
int color = new ArgbEvaluator().evaluate(getAdapterPosition()/365f, Color.GREEN, Color.RED);
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(color);
view.setBackground(cd);
```

Comment: Im a bit confused about "getAdapterPosition()", can you explain it ? Also I used this code onItemClickListener so it shows colors when I click on item and I need those colors to stay on item when I open the list activity how can I solve this ? btw I use listView not recyclerView

Comment: The `getAdapterPosition()` would translate to `position` (first argument) in `getView` of the `ListView`'s adapter. Also, If your item is clickable, you can create an empty `View` inside your layout with `match_parent` for both its width and height, and give the provided background to that view.